# Referencing Doxygen tables

Tags: doxygen, cross-reference

Let's say I have this table written as a comment in a file that Doxygen goes through:

```
<table>
<caption id="cpsm_commands">CPSM (Module 0) - Command palette</caption>
<tr><th>Command      <th>Abbreviation          <th>Description
<tr><td>0x01         <td>SEND_CMD_MMC_NORESP   <td>Send a command to the eMMC that doesn't expect any response.
<tr><td>0x02         <td>SEND_CMD_MMC_RESP     <td>Send a command to the eMMC that expects a standard response (6 bytes).
<tr><td>0x03         <td>SEND_CMD_MMC_RESP_EXT <td>Send a command to the eMMC that expects an extended response (17 bytes).
<tr><td>0x04         <td>FETCH_RESP            <td>Retrieve a response that has been previously buffered and transmit it through SPI.
<tr><td>0x05         <td>FETCH_RESP_EXT        <td>Retrieve an extended response that has been previously buffered and transmit it through SPI.
<tr><td>0x1E         <td>GET_STATUS            <td>Get current status of the CPSM (see \ref status_register).
<tr><td>0x1F         <td>CANCEL_WAITING        <td>If the CPSM is waiting for a response, this command allows the state machine to go back to IDLE.
</table>
```

How do I reference it more extensively? `\ref cpsm_commands` will only print the id of the caption, I want to replace that text and keep the link to the table.

I have tried `\ref cpsm_commands [some text]` but it just prints `some_text` in the HTML and I lose the hyperlink.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you have a look at:
\anchor <word>
This command places an invisible, named anchor into the documentation to which you can refer with the \ref command.